# Listing authors sequentially with affiliations without 'and' operator

Tags: formatting, titles

I'm having problems listing authors in a way that doesn't cause a strange 'and' operator to appear between names, as well as names to appear on completely different lines.  Sometimes it goes away and sometimes it appears, sometimes between authors 1 and 2 while sometimes between authors 1 and 3, depending on how much text I insert into the main body of the document.  Here's an example ('and' operator between authors 2 and 3):

[image]

I would like to format the author list to be listed sequentially: Name1, Name2, Name3 with all the respective University names, department names, and addresses included directly below     the one-liner of author names. Pretty classic stuff.

Since I'm using `twocolumn`, the closest related issue I could find to this is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041809/latex-multiple-authors-in-a-two-column-article

I could not solve my issues with that SO link.  Can someone please offer assistance to make things right in the code used to generate the output above:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, prl]{revtex4}

\makeindex

%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\title{My title}

\author{Name1}
\email{email1@email.com}
\affiliation{University name \\ Department name\\ Address}

\author{Name2}
\email{email2@email.com}
\affiliation{University name\\ Department name \\ Address}

\author{Name3}
\email{email3@email.com}
\affiliation{University name\\ Department name \\ Address}


\begin{abstract}
  The abstract starts here.  Filling space now: etc etc etc...
\end{abstract}


\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

My introduction starts here...

\end{document}
```

Comment: In your code, authors 2 and 3 are grouped because their affiliation is exactly the same (the affiliation for author 1 has an extra space and thus is singled out). If you want all the authors in the same line, you could do `\author{Name1, Name 2, Name 3}` and `\affiliation{Affiliation 1\\Affiliation 2\\Affiliation 3}`... but this is just a hack and probably it would be better to use another class if you are free to do it (and if you are using this class to submit a paper to a journal, surely they will not appreciate that you try to change the format)

Comment: This bunches everything up into an unreadable format.  Perhaps I can use the `authblk` package with similar \author and \affiliation etc formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, prl]{revtex4}

%\makeindex

%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\title{My title}

\author
{Name 1,$^{1}$ Name 2,$^{2}$ Name 3$^{1\ast}$\\
\normalsize{$^{1}$Department Name, University Name,}\\
\normalsize{..................................................... Some potentially very long address .....................................................}\\
\normalsize{$^{2}$Department Name, University Name, Some short address}\\
\normalsize{$^\ast$To whom correspondence should be addressed: email3@email.com.}
}


\begin{abstract}
  The abstract starts here.  Filling space now: etc etc etc...
\end{abstract}

\maketitle


\section{Introduction}

My introduction starts here...

\end{document}
```

[image]